# glossary_config error when trying to use a glossary to translate text

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I have successfully created a glossary to the cloud which I can successfully list, but when trying to use it to test the translation out, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\gtranstest2.py", line 57, in <module>
    translate_text_with_glossary(eng,pid,gid)
  File "C:\py\gtranstest2.py", line 45, in translate_text_with_glossary
    response = client.translate_text(
TypeError: translate_text() got an unexpected keyword argument 'glossary_config'
```

My code (which is based on their example code provided here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#v3):

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3


eng = "H1 High beam, H1 Low beam (included)"
pid = "[HIDDEN]"




def translate_text_with_glossary(
    text,
    project_id,
):
    """Translates a given text using a glossary."""

    client = translate_v3.TranslationServiceClient()
    parent = 'projects/[HIDDEN]/locations/us-central1'


    glossary_config = translate_v3.types.TranslateTextGlossaryConfig(glossary="projects/[HIDDEN]/locations/us-central1/glossaries/kittglossaryv2")

    # Supported language codes: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages
    response = client.translate_text(
        contents=[text],
        target_language_code="en",
        source_language_code="hu",
        parent=parent,
        glossary_config=glossary_config,
    )
    print("Translated text: \n")
    for translation in response.glossary_translations:
        # print(u"\t {}".format(translation.translated_text))
        return translation.translated_text

translate_text_with_glossary(eng,pid)
```

glossary_config should be the correct argument so I don't understand the error at all. I would appreciate any help

Comment: I suppose that you've wrongly defined `glossary` resource path under [TranslateTextGlossaryConfig()](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/gapic/v3/types.html#google.cloud.translate_v3.types.TranslateTextGlossaryConfig). Have you tried to use [glossary_path()](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/gapic/v3/api.html#google.cloud.translate_v3.TranslationServiceClient.glossary_path) method to set `glossary` variable?

Comment: So like this? `glossary = client.glossary_path(project_id, "us-central1", glossary_id)` ? Same error, sorry if I misunderstood your comment, still really new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me copy user Paddy Alton's answer from another question that helped me partially solve my issue:

---

Also encountered this. Not all the documentation has been updated yet, but they have published a migration guide:

https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/UPGRADING.html

You could replace `parent` with `"projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<LOCATION>"`

or define

```py
def location_path(project_id, location):
    # might as well use an f-string, the new library supports python >=3.6
    return f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"
```

and change `client.location_path` to `location_path` if this is something you use in many locations.

There are more sweeping changes, too. They now prefer you to pass a dictionary called `request` to the API methods, although the old way is still accepted. Thus, your code might look like this:

```py
from google.cloud import translate_v3 as translate

client = translate.TranslationServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

response = client.translate_text(
    request={
        "parent": "projects/my-location/locations/global",
        "target_language_code": target_language_code,
        "contents": [text],
    }
)
```

Now, you might well ask 'how will I know what to put in that request dictionary?'. It looks as though the library comes with type annotations for the dictionaries appropriate for each method: https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/translate_v3/types.html

For example, I read in your comment on another answer that you have had trouble with the `detect_language` method. The method signature indicates that if you use keyword arguments, `content` should be a valid one, so I don't know why that fails - maybe it's a bug.

However, if instead you use a `request` dictionary, that should look [like this](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/translate_v3/types.html#google.cloud.translate_v3.types.DetectLanguageRequest). You'll see that the keys don't appear to correspond exactly to the method signature keywords (although `content` is one of them).

This code would work:

```py
response = client.detect_language({
    "parent": "projects/my-location/locations/global",
    "content": "Tá Gaeilge Agam, ach tá mé i mo chonai i Sasana",
})

lang = response.languages[0].language_code
```

(the return type is somewhat convoluted, as you can see)

---

Now after changing the code like this:

```
response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "contents": [text],
            "source_language_code": "en",
            "target_language_code": "hu",            
            "parent": parent,
            "glossary_config": glossary_config,
           }
    )
```

I get no glossary_config error and the code returns a translation. My only problem is now that the result translation I get doesn't seem to use my provided glossary even though it says it does. But this probably should be another thread.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your code with my experimental data, modifying a bit **parent** and **glossary_config** argument definitions entire [translate_text()](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/gapic/v3/api.html#google.cloud.translate_v3.TranslationServiceClient.translate_text) method referring to the [example](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#v3) from documentation, `translate_text_with_glossary()` function works as intended.

```
client = translate_v3.TranslationServiceClient()

parent = client.location_path("Project_ID", "us-central1")
glossary = client.glossary_path("Project_ID", "us-central1", "Glossary-ID")

glossary_config = translate_v3.types.TranslateTextGlossaryConfig(glossary=glossary)
```

Please keep in mind that sharing personal identifiable information such as unique account identifiers within either code examples or the question description may significantly increase a risk of harmful events compromising customer computation resources.

Comment: Even with your changes I get the same "unexpected keyword argument" error. Don't get what I'm doing wrong here. Translations without a glossary works.

Comment: Do you have the same error running the pure code from [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/translate/cloud-client/translate_v3_translate_text_with_glossary.py) with your data?

Comment: Yes I did, but this migration guide solved it: https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/UPGRADING.html